# Using ArcPy from ArcGIS Pro to add the same value to all rows in a new field

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I've created a new field called Year and want to add in the same value (e.g. 2017) to all rows. I know I can do this in Field Calculator, but it is part of a bigger process which I'd like to automate.

Comment: CalculateField can be used from code, and is generally the fastest tool for that purpose. What have you tried? What problem did you encounter? You will need to [Edit] the Question to provide a representative code sample.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using an [Update Cursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) to manipulate feature class attributes. Here is an example that adds an integer value from the `yr` variable to the `YEAR` field. Note that if your field type is string type, you will need to change the `yr = 2017` variable to `yr = '2017'`.

```
import arcpy

# Specify your input feature class
fc = 'c:/path/to/your/file_geodatabase.gdb/feature_class'
field = ['YEAR'] # This is the field you wish to update

yr = 2017 # Some value to add to the field (Note that this is an integer data type so your field must be integer too)

# Create update cursor for feature class 
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field) as cursor: 
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = yr
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```